# Как получить объект определенной структуры на основе данных из БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Я столкнулся с проблемой и никак не могу ее решить.
Имеются данные в таблице БД:

```
 **User**       **Depart**       **A**       **B**
  User_1         Depart 1          1           2
  User_1         Depart 1          11          22
  User_2         Depart 1          222         333
  User_3         Depart 1          333         444
  User_4         Depart 2          1111        2222
  User_4         Depart 2          33333       44444
```

Можно ли получая данные из БД, построить объект необходимой структуры:

```
obj = {
  "depart 1":
    {
      "user_1": [{
                    a: "1",
                    b: "2"
                  },
                  {
                    a: "11",
                    b: "22"
                  }],
      "user_2": [{
                    a: "222",
                    b: "333"
                  }],
      "user_3": [{
                    a: "333",
                    b: "444"
                  }]
    },
  "depart 2":
    {
      "user_4": [{
                    a: "1111",
                    b: "2222"
                  }],
      "user_5": [{
                    a: "33333",
                    b: "44444"
                  }]
    }
}
```

с этим объектом я буду работать дальше в js, но для начала надо его как то состряпать. Подскажите как быть.

**update:** работаю с БД MSSQL.

Comment: Составить класс подобной структуры, получить его из базы (что у вас? EF, linq, dapper?), сериализовать при помощи json.net. В чём именно вопрос? Вы с базами работали в своём проекте? Что у вас за база? ms sql/ mysql / postgre? Давайте либо вопрос будет о json (тогда добавляйте метку json и свой класс которым вы читаете из базы), либо о базе (тогда добавляйте метку и информацию по чтению из базы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Типа получаем из БД
var users = new UserInfo[]
{
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_1", Depart = "Depart_1", A = "1", B = "2"},
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_1", Depart = "Depart_1", A = "11", B = "22"},
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_2", Depart = "Depart_1", A = "222", B = "333"},
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_3", Depart = "Depart_1", A = "333", B = "444"},
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_4", Depart = "Depart_2", A = "1111", B = "2222"},
    new UserInfo(){User = "User_4", Depart = "Depart_2", A = "33333", B = "44444"},
};

// Формируем что будем сериализовать
var toSerialize = users.GroupBy(x => x.Depart)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.GroupBy(u => u.User)
        .ToDictionary(u => u.Key, u => u.Select(z => new {z.A, z.B}).ToArray()));

// сериализуем
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

// вывод
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

На выходе получаем

```
{
  "Depart_1": {
    "User_1": [
      {
        "A": "1",
        "B": "2"
      },
      {
        "A": "11",
        "B": "22"
      }
    ],
    "User_2": [
      {
        "A": "222",
        "B": "333"
      }
    ],
    "User_3": [
      {
        "A": "333",
        "B": "444"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Depart_2": {
    "User_4": [
      {
        "A": "1111",
        "B": "2222"
      },
      {
        "A": "33333",
        "B": "44444"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```